# VB.NET Extension on Nullable(Of T) object, gives type error

Tags: vb.net, nullable, generics

The code I want to work:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function NValue(Of T)(ByVal value As Nullable(Of T), ByVal DefaultValue As T) As T
    Return If(value.HasValue, value.Value, DefaultValue)
End Function
```

So basically what I want it to do, is to give along a default value to a nullable object, and depending on if it's null or not, it will give its own value or the default one.

So with a Date object, it would do this, which works, but I can't get it to work with the generic T:

```
<Extension()>
Public Function NValue(ByVal value As Date?, ByVal DefaultValue As Date) As Date
  Return If(value.HasValue, value.Value, DefaultValue)
End Function

Dim test As Date? = Nothing
Dim result = test.NValue(DateTime.Now)
```

The variable 'result' now has the current DateTime.

When I try it with T, I get this as error (which Visual Studio puts on the T in Nullable(Of T):
Type 'T' must be a value type or a type argument constrained to 'Structure' in order to be used with 'Nullable' or nullable modifier '?'.

Thank you very much for any help!

Greetings

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
Public Function NValue(Of T as Structure)(ByVal value As Nullable(Of T as Structure), ByVal DefaultValue As T) As T
```

I'm not sure if you need both `as Structure` clauses or not.

**Update**

Per the comment below, only the first clause is required:

```
Public Function NValue(Of T as Structure)(ByVal value As Nullable(Of T), ByVal DefaultValue As T) As T
```

Comment: Only the first `As Structure` clause is needed, the second one will cause a syntax error. Apart from that, this is correct.

Comment: I thought that might be the case.  I haven't had need to use this yet myself, but I knew it was possible.

Comment: FYI, When I define & use as an extension method, NValue does not show up in Intellisense, and if I type it anyway it appears in Red, hovering over says `Cannot resolve symbol NValue` (VS 2010 + ReSharper 6.1 + .Net 3.5). Oddly, it does compile & run fine. `Dim nullval As Integer? = Nothing`, `Dim result As Integer = nullval.NValue(42)`.

Answer (score 3):

Your function is a bit redundant because the same can be achieved by `If`:

```
Dim nullval As Integer? = Nothing
Dim value  = If(nullval, 42)
```

This is the same as what you’ve written, namely:

```
Dim value = If(nullval.HasValue, nullval.Value, 42)
```

It’s the equivalent to C#’s null coercion operator `??` (`var value = nullval ?? 42;`).

Comment: I know it is, but I have to use it often so an extension would make it all shorter and more neat.

Comment: @FrieK: if you know it why did you write it differently in your extension method? Apart from that, I don’t find your method neater than using `If`. Now, if you had used `[Or]` as the method name, this would allow writing `nullval.Or(42)`. Now *that* would indeed be neat.

Comment: Ohh I misunderstood, I'm sorry. You're right, just that If(..,..) would indeed be shorter, and Or is indeed a good idea, that would make it easier to read.

Comment: @FrieK: How is `myvar.NValue(42)` or `myvar.Or(42)` preferable to `If(myvar, 42)`? The latter is about the same length, and uses a standard VB feature `If`, so is more readily understood by whoever has to read your code in the future. Well, it is once they read about that binary form of the If, which isn't as commonly used IMHO as the terniary form `If(cond,then,else)`. First time I ever saw it used is here, but now that I know about it, I know to look for it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the answer to this question and was pleased with Andrew Cooper's solution, but I couldn't get it to work in practice, though it would compile. If I tried to invoke the extension method on the Nullable in question, I would not see my extension method in the list of available methods. If I called it directly, I would receive the following error "'System.Nullable' does not satisfy the 'Structure' constraint for type parameter 'T'. Only non-nullable 'Structure' types are allowed." I found a possible explanation for this error [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vladimirsadov/archive/2005/06/03/425097.aspx).

I used the overload of GetValueOrDefault() with no parameters, as it seemed to accomplish my initial goal. After some [research](http://www.phoenixcode.net/post/2009/09/18/Which-1-to-use-or-GetValueOrDefault%28%29.aspx), I am comfortable that GetValueOrDefault() is an adequate, if not preferable solution. In FrieK's case, I would elect to use the overload of GetValueOrDefault() with defaultValue as a parameter.

---

Comment: When you say you couldn't get it to work, it would be good if you provided the exact code you did. I think you either defined or called it incorrectly; we aren't trying to pass a Nullable as a Structure. `T` is a `Structure`, but the parameter `value` is a `Nullable(Of T)`. So, we are passing a Nullable in to a Nullable, not to a Structure. "Calling it directly" works - though you have to specify `(Of Integer)` to use it "directly" (rather than as an extension method): `Dim nullval As Integer? = Nothing`, `Dim result = NValue(Of Integer)(nullval, 42)`.